# G Suite for Business- change the primary account & phone number

Tags: google-workspace-for-business

using GAM (https://github.com/jay0lee/GAM) for managing the Google Domain.

there is a certain command "gam info domain" that prints some information about the primary owner and the domain when it was registered also it prints the Google internal customer number.

In addition to all of that it prints

contactName
Phone

It looks like a customer chooses these when registering at G Suite for the first time.

My question is, does anyone have an idea where I can change both these values? Since we have a new CEO and he got another phone I just want to have it there - if its possible.

I already opened a ticket at Google Cloud Support and they pointed me to Stackoverflow. Literally they dont know themselves but assume you folks would know. Well here I am.

Answer (score 1):

You can run:

```
gam update customer contactName "Juan Perez" countryCode "AR" phoneNumber "+5491155555555"
```

> notice that you'll need to specify some of the fields even though they aren't changing so they won't get blanked out.

Source:
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-apps-manager/HHO0xHkK8bk/nLhfFh8WBAAJ